# If file doesn't exist, try again

Tags: java, readfile

I'm trying to make a program where it will read a file if it exists. If the file doesn't exist then I want it to loop back and ask the user again for the input. At the moment I've got this where it will just come to a stop but I wanted it to loop back and ask again, any ideas?

```
System.out.println("Enter the file you want to check (without file extension): ");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.nextLine();
String in = (input + ".txt");

File f = new File(in);

if(!f.exists()) {
    System.out.println(in + " doesn't exist! Try again.");
    return;
}


String fileName = input;
String content = readFile(in);
System.out.println(content);
```

Comment: So, why don't you surround your code with a loop?

Answer (score 3):

One way is to use a `do`, `while(false)` loop (which allows `f` to be scoped to the loop body):

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
do {
    System.out.println("Enter the file you want to check (without file extension): ");        
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    String in = (input + ".txt");

    File f = new File(in);
    if(!f.exists()){
        System.out.println(in + " doesn't exist! Try again.");
        continue; /*go round again*/
    }
} while (false/*i.e. exit the loop if we get here*/);
```

If you want `f` to be available after the loop then declare `File f;` just before the `do {` line, and write `f = new File(in);` in the loop body.

Comment: The `Scanner` should probably be outside the loop.

Comment: Don't do a `continue; while(false)`. Just do `while (!f.exists())` or skip the do part and do `while (true) { code if (f.exists()) break; }`

Comment: Woah, does `continue` bypass a `do...while` loop condition? :o Why didn't I know this?

Comment: @MuratK. : that is a good point. Thank you.

Comment: @marisbest2: I disagree. There's nothing wrong with a `while(false)`: it's idiomatic. Testing `!f.exists()` at the top means the scope of `f` has to be outside the loop, and could even cause an NPE.

Comment: I wanted to be able to use in, input, and content outside of the loop, could this be done?

Comment: Yup. I state so in my last sentence. Also, declare `in` outside the body of the loop.

Comment: I was just about to answer with a `while(true)` loop, but I like your `do ... while(false)` approach better as I think it hints at least a little that the intended happy-case behaviour is not to loop...

Comment: I don't like `while(true)`: always seems to be a recipe for an infinite loop. And, as you say, `while(false)` immediately signals a contrivance. But do consider answering: SO works best when there is a selection of answers to choose from.

Comment: I always feel that `while (false)` implies that a loop will never run. And I avoid using continue wherever possible. Breaks are bad, but not as bad. I'd probably actually do something where you dont use a do while.

Answer (score 1):

Just to provide you with a more classical `while` loop to do this.

Note that the answer by @Bathsheba is really neat, you should definitely accept his answer.

```
System.out.println("Enter the file you want to check (without file extension): ");
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = scanner.nextLine();
String in = (input + ".txt");
File file = new File(input);

while(!file.exists()){

    System.out.println(in + " doesn't exist! Try again.");
    input = scanner.nextLine();
    in = (input + ".txt");
    file = new File(input);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont like `do`-`while` and `while(false)` or even `while(true)` and `break`s.

If its not too much work, I'd do something like:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
File f = getFile();
while (!f.exist()) {
    f = getFile();
}

private File getFile() {
    System.out.println("Enter the file you want to check (without file extension): ");        
    String input = scanner.nextLine();
    String in = (input + ".txt");
    File f = new File(in);
    if (!f.exists()) {
        System.out.println(in + " doesn't exist! Try again.");
    }
    return f;
}
```

This avoids ugly do-while loops and encapsulates the getting logic well. You could also theoretically make it recursive (although that allows for stack overflows) or have it return a `Pair` of `File, in` which raises the input to the outer loop thus allowing the loop to have access to the `in` variable.